# Is It Possible to Generate Case Statements with a Loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a script in my project that will generate notifications, though, these notifications thus far have the same title and description through their pre-defined variables:

```
    notificationTitle: "Notification",
    notificationDescription: "This is a notification.",
```

This is rather boring, really. And whilst I can go and set the amount of notifications* I want the script to generate, along with enough case statements to facilitate them, this is not reasonable. In the environment where we intend to have multiple different notifications for multiple different users, I don't want to have to write a case statement for each one, like so:

```
function setNotificationDescription(iteration) {
    "use strict";

    switch (iteration) {
    case 1:
        values.notificationDescription = "One";
        break;
    case 2:
        values.notificationDescription = "Two";
        break;
    case 3:
        values.notificationDescription = "Three";
        break;
    case 4:
        values.notificationDescription = "Four";
        break;
    case 5:
        values.notificationDescription = "Five";
        break;
    case 6:
        values.notificationDescription = "Six";
        break;
    default:
        values.notificationDescription = "Seven";

    }
}
```

*This would be filled by a count of objects in a JSON file in the future, but for my example I set it myself.

**Live Example**: http://moonsquads.com/scriptbase/notification-generation/

---

Is there a way to generate these case statements automatically?

Comment: I don't quite understand which part of the page used a case-statement...
As you are having "objects of similar structure", maybe you can consider using an array of objects like `notifications = [{"title": "Title", "description": "Description"}]` so that you can access the objects with a for-loop instead of a case-switch?

Comment: @SunnyPun I've added the ``case`` statement to my question. As for where the function is called, it is called in the ``while`` loop, and passed the current iteration count: ``setNotificationDescription(values.iteratedNotificationAmount);``

Comment: What is the source of your messages? Does it something like array?

Comment: Just use an array with indices instead of a  `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the `values.notificationDescription` inside the function, I have moved it outside for demonstration purposes (compare the "case-version" with the "array-version"):
https://jsfiddle.net/6j98sxue/1/

This avoids switch-cases by using an array since numeric index is concerned, and avoids a big change to your original code.

In addition to the above, I would suggest a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) post and people there would give detailed comments on refactoring the existing code.  Modifying the `value` object and getting values from it will cause problem, e.g. it is hard to test the code as we cannot do dependency injection.